# 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, but I can't identify where it asks for an integer

Tags: python

I encounter this error message `'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`when running the following code:

```
from scipy.integrate import nquad
from numpy import sqrt, sin, cos, pi, arcsin, maximum, log, log10, exp
from matplotlib.pyplot import xscale, yscale, plot, show, savefig

#define constants
msun=1500
m1=30*msun
m2=30*msun
M=m1+m2
eta=m1*m2/M**2
mSMBH=4.2*10**6*msun
v=5/10**4
pc=3.09*10**16
r0=1.005*10**21              #nfw parameter#
rho0=1.27/10**49             #nfw parameter#
pmtpy=3*10**8*365*24*3600    #rate from per-meter to per-yr
rhoc=1.35*10**(-53)
cm=2.16

#define functions
def g(x):
    return log(1+x)-x/(1+x)
def y(x):
    return 1.43*10**12*1500/x
def sig(x):
    return 13.216*y(x)**0.41/(1+1.102*y(x)**0.2+6.22*y(x)**0.333)
def c(x):
    return 2.881*(1+(sig(x)/1.257)**1.022)*exp(0.06/sig(x)**2)
def r0(x):
    return (3*x/(800*c(x)**3*rhoc*pi))**(1/3)
def rho0(x):
    return 200*rhoc*c(x)**3/3/g(c(x))
def sigma(x):
    return sqrt(4*pi*rho0(x)*r0(x)**2*g(cm)/cm)
def mSMBH(x):
    return 1500*10**(8.15+4.38*log10(1500*sigma(x)))
def rcap(x):
    return 8*mSMBH(x)

def Rsp(x):
    return 0.122*sqrt(mSMBH(x)/rho0(x)/r0(x))
def rhosp(r,x):
    return 3*rho0(x)*r0(x)*Rsp(x)**(4/3)*(1-rcap(x)/r)**3/r**(7/3)

#x,y,z are to be integrated, and m is the x-axis parameter to be searched through using while loop
def v(z,m):
    return sqrt(mSMBH(m)/z)
def vrel(y,z,m):
    return 2*v(z,m)*sin(y/2)
def vcm(y,z,m):
    return 2*v(z,m)*cos(y/2)
def bmin(y,z,m):
    return 2*M/vrel(y,z,m)
def bmax(y,z,m):
    return maximum(bmin(y,z,m), M*(340*eta/(3*cos(1)*vrel(y,z,m)**9))**(1/7))
def a(x,y,z,m):
    if bmax(y,z,m)>bmin(y,z,m):
        return M/(vrel(y,z,m)**2*((bmax(y,z,m)/x)**7-1))
    else:
        return 0
def rt(x,y,z,m):
    return a(x,y,z,m)*(mSMBH(m)/M)**(1/3)
def rd(x,y,z,m):
    return maximum(rcap(m),rt(x,y,z,m))
def rz(x,y,z,m):
    return rd(x,y,z,m)*(sqrt(1+8*mSMBH(m)/(rd(x,y,z,m)*vcm(y,z,m)**2))-1)/2
def thetal(x,y,z,m):
    if rd(x,y,z,m)<z and rz(x,y,z,m)<z:
        return arcsin(rd(x,y,z,m)*sqrt(2*(vcm(y,z,m)**2/2-mSMBH(m)/z+mSMBH(m)/rd(x,y,z,m)))/(vcm(y,z,m)*z))
    else:
        return pi/2

#prepare looping tools    
m=10**9*msun
M=[]           #x value array
Rate=[]        #result estimation array
RateUp=[]      #result upper bound array
RateDown=[]    #result lower bound array
options={'limit':200}

while m<10**14*msun:
    def zbound():
        return [rcap(m),Rsp(m)]
    def ybound(z_foo):
        return [10**(-10),pi-10**(-10)]
    def xbound(y,z):
        return [bmin(y,z,m)-10**(-6),bmax(y,z,m)-10**(-6)]
    def f(x,y,z):
        return pmtpy*8*pi**2*v(z,m)/m1**2*rhosp(z,m)**2*z**2*sin(y/2)**2*cos(y/2)*x*cos(thetal(x,y,z,m))
    ans=nquad(f, [xbound,ybound,zbound],opts=[options,options,options])   
    M.append(m)
    Rate.append(ans[0])
    RateUp.append(ans[0]+ans[1])
    RateDown.append(ans[0]-ans[1])
    m+=10**15

xscale('log')
yscale('log')
plot(M,Rate,M,RateUp,M,RateDown)
show()
```

Basically I am trying to evaluate a triple integral dependent on the parameter m. The error occurs specifically at

```
    File "C:/Users/user/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 83, in xbound
        return [bmin(y,z,m)-10**(-6),bmax(y,z,m)-10**(-6)]
    File "C:/Users/user/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 52, in bmax
        return maximum(bmin(y,z,m), M*(340*eta/(3*cos(1)*vrel(y,z,m)**9))**(1/7))

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

But I really cannot tell why an integer is in need anywhere in 'bmax' in my code. Any idea what might be the problem? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: In general, may I suggest using `import numpy as np` and then `np.sin`, `np.cos` etc wherever you need? It will make the code easier to maintain, and easier for others to understand it too.

Comment: @VBB Thx for the suggestion. But may I ask why it helps to maintain the code? I always thought my method simplifies the code and is more straight forward to understand.

Comment: One of the reasons (which I care about): Eventually you will have more complicated codes, and you will have function names which exist in multiple packages. For instance, there is `math.sin` which does not support numpy arrays as inputs. So you are setting yourself up for getting confused while debugging later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is arising because you have `M=[]`, which makes it a `list`. That completely overrides the `M = m1 + m2` you have done at the top. Then on line 55, you have `M * BLAH`, where `M` is NOT a numpy array (it is a list), hence the `*` operator is interpreted to mean "Repeat the list BLAH times". That's where the problem is.

PS: changing it to `np.array(M) * (340*eta/(3*cos(1.)*vrel(y,z,m)**9))**(1/7)` fixes this problem but creates others. For instance if you are using python2, then `(1/7) = 0`, you probably want `(1./7.)`, and so on. You know the masses upfront - so it will probably be faster to use `np.arange` to create the full `M` array and then process it.

PS: Since you have astronomy related calculations, do check out the `astropy` package, it does some of the things you are looking for.

Comment: Thx so much! This is exactly the problem. I was actually intending the M for m1+m2, so I will just need to rename the M list. And thx for the recommendation, I will definitely check out 'astropy' later.